# Mysql high CPU and RAM usage

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql server which has 60gb of ram and it uses too much system resources. Top command result;

```
Mem:   64555285k total, 64151125k used
```

I think there is something terribly wrong with my mysql conf.Here is my mysql conf;

```
[mysqld]
max-allowed-packet=400M
max_connections=8000
query_cache_size = 50M
thread_cache_size =32
table_open_cache = 1000
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 35G   
innodb_log_buffer_size = 70M
join_buffer_size= 8G
tmp_table_size = 64M
max_heap_table_size = 64M
query_cache_type = 1
```

Is there anything wrong with my mysql conf?

Answer (score 0):

`join_buffer_size= 8G` is dangerously high.  If you have a lot of queries running, all needing the "join buffer", you could quickly run out of RAM, as you appear to have.

`8M` is a better value for that setting.  Keep in mind that if a query 'wants' a join buffer, it will either use the space you provide or perform the query a different way.

`max_connections=8000` is quite high.  What is the status value of `Max_used_connections`?  If it is more than a few hundred, we should discuss why it is so large.  That could have an impact on memory usage -- many things are "per connection".

Another possibility...  What else is running?  Could it be chewing up RAM?

For a more thorough review, provide `SHOW VARIABLES;` and `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;` (perhaps on some postit site).